# resteasy return 403 not handle in junit

Tags: java, junit, resteasy

This is in a reference of

[Return HTTP error from RESTeasy interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694169/return-http-error-from-resteasy-interface)

I am doing the same just for reference

```
@Path("/foo")
public class FooBar {

    @GET
    @Path("/bar")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Object testMethod(@HeaderParam("var_1") @DefaultValue("") String var1,
                             @HeaderParam("var_2") @DefaultValue("") String var2 {

        if (var1.equals(var2)) {
            return "All Good";
        } else {
            throw new WebApplicationException(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }
    }
 }
```

But when it throws the error I can not catch it in my junit test. It is not comming in any asserts below.

```
@Test
    @RunAsClient
    public void test403() {
        try {
            Object obj = fooBarService.testMethod("test2", "test");
            Assert.assertFalse(true);
        } catch(WebApplicationException ex) {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

How to check the 403 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client doesn't get the exception - that is turned in to an HTTP STATUS = 403 that is part of the response object you get back from the request.  You need to check the http status value vs 403.